# Compute:$\int_{C}F.\tau ds$ where $F(x, y, z) = xi - yj - zk.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $C$ be the equatorial circle on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$
and let $\tau$ be the unit tangent vector to $C$ taken in the anticlockwise sense. Compute:$$\int_{C}F.\tau ds$$
where $F(x, y, z) = xi - yj - zk.$

**My attempt** : Here div $F= 1-1-1=-1$

$$\int_{C}F.\tau ds=\int \int \int_{B(0,1)} -1.dxdydz$$

since it is sphere  so $dxdydz= r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d \phi$

$$\implies\int_{C}F.\tau ds= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0 }^{1} -1r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d \phi =2\pi.2 .\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

**Is it true** ?

Comment: Why do you think the equality $\int_C F\cdot \tau \,ds=\iiint_B \mathrm{div}F\,dV$ would hold?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz from the  Divergence theorem

Comment: That lets you interchange between volume intergrals and surface integrals over the boundary of the volume.

Comment: Please apply Stokes' theorem and find curl of the vector field instead (which by the way seems zero)

Comment: $\int_{C}F.\tau ds = \iint_S (\nabla \times F) \cdot dS$ where $S$ is a surface whose boundary is curve $C$.

Comment: We can also rather simply apply the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integration since the field is conservative. (this is equivalent to Math Lover's answer because the curl of any conservative vector field is always zero)